# cmake CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH not working with set()

Tags: c++, cmake, clion, cmake-modules

I have an external SDK which has all the libs and includes on.

Now to make it work, I need to set `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` with my path, so I'm trying to set the variable inside of CMake file like this:

```
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/my/path/to/SDK")
```

But for some reason is not working as I would expect because it's not going to find some packages with the function `pkg_check_modules`.

On the other hand, I've I'm going into terminal and I will call CMake like this, everything is fine and this's going to work as intended.

```
cmake -DCMAKE_PREFIX_PATH=/my/path/to/SDK ..
```

Here it's a part of my CMake file:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.7)

set(PKG_CONFIG_USE_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ON)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/my/path/to/SDK")

project(wayland_egl C CXX)

include(FindPkgConfig)

pkg_check_modules(WLCLIENT REQUIRED wayland-webos-client)
include_directories(${WLCLIENT_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Could one of you guys explain to me why is this happening and how can I fix my CMake file to work it properly?

Comment: Did you set the [`PKG_CONFIG_USE_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FindPkgConfig.html#variable:PKG_CONFIG_USE_CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH) variable to 1 to indicate to `pkg_check_modules` to add the paths in `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to the search?

Comment: yes I did, but it's exctly the same